# how to access div within the element, such as button using css? So, that I can use hover function on div either css or jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<table><t head><tr><t h><button><div>
```

Is it possibl to get my `div`? Because I need to use the `hover` function on that `div`.

Answer (score 1):

```
table > th > button div
```

Or

```
table > th > button > div
```

Or

```
table th button div
```

Or if you want to select first div

```
table > th > button div:first-child
```

**For jQuery you can use next:**

```
$(".selector").hover(function () {
  //stuff to do on mouse enter 
}, function () {
  //stuff to do on mouse leave 
});
```

.hover() has it's own handler: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 0):

`$('table th div')` will do it.

I would highly suggest you read the [selectors section of the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) as this really is jQuery 101.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery :

```
 $("table th div").mouseover(function() {
 //To Do
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ">" to find the child element in css

for eg

```
button > div
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
  $( this ).next().hover(
function() {  $( this ).css("backgroundColor","red");
});
```